# Sum of column values of dataframes with date time index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have two dataframes like this:

df1:

```
Timestamp    Consumption
2017-03-21    2903
2017-03-22    2982
2017-03-23    3011
2017-03-24    2964
2017-03-25    2961
2017-03-26    2967
2017-03-27    2967
2017-03-28    2903
2017-03-29    2923
2017-03-30    3032
```

df2:

```
Timestamp             Consumption
2017-03-21 23:00:00    2000.0
2017-03-22 23:00:00    2005.0
2017-03-23 23:00:00    2026.0
2017-03-24 23:00:00    1919.0
2017-03-25 23:00:00    1933.0
2017-03-26 23:00:00    2006.0
2017-03-27 23:00:00    1995.0
2017-03-28 23:00:00    1998.0
2017-03-29 23:00:00    2002.0
2017-03-30 23:00:00    1730.0
```

I want to add the values of Consumption column with respective date but i couldn't able to do that.

Desired output:

```
Timestamp    Consumption
2017-03-21    4903
2017-03-22    4987
2017-03-23    5037
2017-03-24    4883
2017-03-25    4894
2017-03-26    4973
2017-03-27    4962
2017-03-28    4901
2017-03-29    4925
2017-03-30    4762
```

I tried this:

```
sum = df1['Consumption'] + df2['Consumption'][match(df1.index,df2.index)]
```

Output:

```
Timestamp           Consumption
2017-03-21 00:00:00   NaN
2017-03-21 23:00:00   NaN
2017-03-22 00:00:00   NaN
2017-03-22 23:00:00   NaN
2017-03-23 00:00:00   NaN
2017-03-23 23:00:00   NaN
2017-03-24 00:00:00   NaN
2017-03-24 23:00:00   NaN
2017-03-25 00:00:00   NaN
2017-03-25 23:00:00   NaN
2017-03-26 00:00:00   NaN
2017-03-26 23:00:00   NaN
2017-03-27 00:00:00   NaN
2017-03-27 23:00:00   NaN
2017-03-28 00:00:00   NaN
2017-03-28 23:00:00   NaN
2017-03-29 00:00:00   NaN
2017-03-29 23:00:00   NaN
2017-03-30 00:00:00   NaN
2017-03-30 23:00:00   NaN
```

Help me achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create indexes for align data, column `Timestamp` in `df2` is converted to [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Timestamp')
s = df2.set_index(df2.Timestamp.dt.date)
df1['Consumption'] = df1['Consumption'].add(s['Consumption'])
#if necessary convert to int
df1['Consumption'] = df1['Consumption'].astype(int)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
   Timestamp  Consumption
0 2017-03-21         4903
1 2017-03-22         4987
2 2017-03-23         5037
3 2017-03-24         4883
4 2017-03-25         4894
5 2017-03-26         4973
6 2017-03-27         4962
7 2017-03-28         4901
8 2017-03-29         4925
9 2017-03-30         4762
```